# Problem with C library linked to Python interpreter, on Mac OS X

Tags: python, unix, gcc, macos

I'm trying to use a C library that is supposed to be available from Python.  The library compiles fine on Mac OS X (10.6.0, i386) with GCC (version: i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5659).

When I try to import the python module from python, I get the error:

```
$ python
Enthought Python Distribution -- www.enthought.com
Version: 7.0-2 (64-bit)

Python 2.7.1 |EPD 7.0-2 (64-bit)| (r271:86832, Dec  3 2010, 15:56:20) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5488)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>> import mymodule
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mymodule/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mymodule import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mymodule/mymodule.so, 2): Symbol not found: _b_char
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mymodule/mymodule.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mymodule/mymodule.so
```

To respond to Ned's questions, this is the output I get:

```
$ file $(python -c 'import sys;print(sys.executable)') 
/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
$ python -c 'import sys;print(sys.maxsize > 2**32)' ;
True
$ cd /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mymodule
$ file mymodule.so 
mymodule.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
$ otool -L mymodule.so
mymodule.so:
    /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.1)
$ file /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib: Mach-O universal binary with 3 architectures
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (for architecture x86_64):   Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (for architecture i386): Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (for architecture ppc7400):  Mach-O dynamically linked shared library ppc
$ file /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib: Mach-O universal binary with 4 architectures
/usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (for architecture i386):    Mach-O dynamically linked shared library i386
/usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
/usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (for architecture ppc): Mach-O dynamically linked shared library ppc
/usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (for architecture ppc64):   Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library ppc64
```

It seems that there's a common architecture, but I'm unsure about whether that's true for the libraries references by otool -L -- those seem to have multiple versions.

Another thing I noticed is that when I make this package and compile it and then make the Python module, the "build" directory of the module (i.e. the directory at the same level as the setup.py file) has these Mac OS X *10.5* files:

```
$ cd build/
$ ls
lib.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7  temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-2.7
```

However, I am using Mac OS X 10.6.  What controls which version is used to compile a Python package using distutils?  I'm afraid this might be causing the problem.

Any idea what could be causing this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to know exactly what the problem is without more information but it appears you are using a 64-bit version of Python (from EPD).  Is the library that you built also built as a 64-bit library?  You should be able to tell by doing something like this:

```
file $(python -c 'import sys;print(sys.executable)')  # see archs that Python was built with
python -c 'import sys;print(sys.maxsize > 2**32)' ; # see if running as 64-bit (false if 32-bit)
cd /Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mymodule
file mymodule.so       # see what architectures the C extension module is built with
otool -L mymodule.so   # see what libraries are referenced by the C extension module
file /path/to/lib1     # see what archs the referenced lib module(s) are built with
```

There needs to be a common arch among all of them.

Update: Based on your additional information, the most suspicious looking item is the library reference to `/usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib`.  That would seem to indicate you have a local copy of `gcc` or other compiler installed in `/usr/local`.  Are you sure you aren't mixing compilers here?  Try cleaning the build directory and explicitly setting `export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.0` before building your module.  Or move that other compiler out of `/usr/local`.  (The 10.5 thing should not be an issue.  That just indicates that the EPD Python distribution was built to run on 10.5 and later systems.)

Comment: I tried it and it does not work unfortunately. I get similar issues when trying to compile other packages, like MySQL-python (which seems notoriously hard to install). When I look in /Developer/SDKs, I have a directory for 10.6 which is not used, so I guess that does mean I have an extra compiler. This is why I was worried about distutils not calling my right version SDK. Any ideas on what could be going on?

Comment: If you are on OS X 10.6 and `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/` is empty, something is wrong with your Xcode installation. You need to install a suitable Xcode 3 for 10.6 (3.2.6 is the current version, I believe)  Avoid the more recent and experimental Xcode 4 for 10.6.  In any case, neither Apple's Xcode Developer Tools nor anything else from Apple, AFAIK, installs anything in `/usr/local`.  If you have  `/usr/local/lib/libgcc*` files there, consider moving them out of the way.  But perhaps they are installed by the EPD distribution.  You might want to ask on their mailing list.